# Open application with explorer.exe but with settings added

Tags: c#, file, batch-file, fivem

When I run this from notepad .bat file it open my application. But when I add `?streamermode=1` at the end it just open blank folder.

```
explorer.exe fivem://connect/IP --> works

explorer.exe fivem://connect/IP?streamerMode=1   --> does not work
```

Answer (score 2):

Command `fivem://connect/IP` is [Uniform Resource Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier)
This command start application associated with that URI

```
explorer.exe "fivem://connect/IP?streamerMode=1"
explorer.exe "https://stackoverflow.com/"
```

Powershell:

```
Start-Process "fivem://connect/IP?streamerMode=1"
```

CMD:

```
start "fivem://connect/IP?streamerMode=1"
```

C#

```
Process.Start("fivem://connect/IP?streamerMode=1")
```

You can also run this command through the browser as site

```
fivem://connect/IP?streamerMode=1
```

Comment: I just decode this command and it works. THANK YOU!!!